# HitTestPoints AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, hittest

I'm having some trouble with my hit test points. I cannot remember how to do them, and my example is to confusing to copy and paste.

Here is my design so far:

[image]

what i wish to do is to make the pinball_mc move back in the direction it's came from when it is hit by either the leftBumper_mc and rightBumper_mc. I think i have to make it * -1 to give it back in the direction it came from. But any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you show your codes?

Comment: If you need any other code just ask. Here's the HTP i had tried:

`if (pinball_mc.hitTestPoint(pinBallTable_mc.x, pinBallTable_mc.y, true) ||
  pinBallTable_mc.hitTestPoint(pinball_mc.x, pinball_mc.y, true))
  {
   pinball_mc.y * -1;
  }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this example: http://raws.adc.rmit.edu.au/~e46191/AS3/AS3_hitTest.html.